# Output Tuple List<int, string> to String without [,] (brackets) appearing

Tags: c#

How do I get rid of the "()" and "," in the output? nivåEtt is a tuple list with string and int.

```cs
            for (int i = 0; i < nivåEtt.Count(); i++)
            {
                tbxNivåTvå.AppendText(nivåEtt[i].ToString() + Environment.NewLine);


            }
```

Output:

```
(Johan Persson      910614      Falköping       , 11)
(Joakim Malmström       910614      Skaraborg       , 23)
```

Desired Output:

```
Johan Persson       910614      Falköping        11
Joakim Malmström        910614      Skaraborg        23
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, could you help us help you and post, for instance an example of the desired output?

Comment: Could you please read [ask] and then provide us with a [mcve] in your question?

Comment: Just access the two items of the tuple manually, and format them into the string however you want. Oh, and you may want to use a `StringBuilder` for building large outputs like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to resolve this:

1. Create a class that extends Tuple, and overrides the ToString() method
2. Instead of using ToString(), just print the items individually yourself:

> ```
> nivåEtt.Sort((a, b) => a.Item2.CompareTo(b.Item2));    
> for (int i = 0; i < nivåEtt.Count(); i++)
> {
>     tbxNivåTvå.AppendText(nivåEtt[i].Item1.ToString() + nivåEtt[i].Item2.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
> }
> ```